# change position of image in image gallery using php

Tags: php, mysql, image

Hi i am working on a photo gallery. Here all images are coming from mysql database table. The images are uploaded from the admin panel. I am using php to upload and fetch images from database table. Till here all things are working fine. Now i have to implement a system where user should be able to define the position of the image in the image gallery and image positions should be swiped with one another image. In the gallery page I am showing 16 images in four rows and after that pagination starts. So will it be possible to implement such a system in my image gallery?

Comment: I think you can use http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Drag-and-Drop-images-from-one-DIV-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx Jquery plugin and Also use the Ajax for updating your database table

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly then you might want to check out this jQuery plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: hi this is fine. but my requirement is that when user selects a position from admin panel the image should be displayed based upon this position id. suppose if the position id of first image is 1 and the selected position id is 2 then no 2 should be updated against the id 1 and position id 1 should be updated against the id 2.